# What is wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked a question yesterday and have received only [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/18819/3961) so far. I personally would not downvote it (nor upvote it), but it has received 6 downvotes without a single comment.

So what's up with that? You know I hate drive by downvoting, so I would like to hear what people think about the post and why it is/should be downvoted.

Comment: I gave it a commentless -1 because I didn't want to argue with the poster. if I had the time, I'd rather have answered it.  I couldn't suggest a way to improve the answer (other than maybe delete it!)

Comment: @PeterTurner Maybe you have something for it now? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer would have people going on a wild goose chase. It makes Catholisism out to have turned completely mystic, upholding other religions as true and one of the late Pope's to be the Antichrist.

I realize it was an attempt to answer the question by pointing out a supposed premise flaw in your question (hence no mod deletion for being out of scope) it does so in a totally bogus way that is not actually representative of Catholic doctrine. In other words it's a wrong answer (hence my downvote).

So why no comment? First of all, it seems patently obvious to me that the answer was wrong. Further more a few clicks through to the author who wrote it and their other posts and profile lead me to believe that I wasn't going to convince them they'd made a mistake by leaving a comment explaining my downvote. It also looked like they were highly likely to argue with me, so I decided not to waste my time.

Frankly it looks like the system is working pretty well. I'd imagine most of the other voters went through a similar thought process. The answer is wrong (and dangerously so) and the community has clearly marked it as such. Comments should be used when a post can be improved and the OP can learn something, not for debating people with bogus theologies. At most it could use a comment would say "This is not representative of Catholisism", but I think the downvotes pretty much speak to that effect already and who wants to leave the comment that's going to make you the target?

There, bulls-eye is on me.

Comment: (I edited, but I haven't voted on this one way or the other.  I'm staying away from that bull's eye.)

Comment: I see your point. It is about half the particular user, and half that the post is disagreeable in general.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks, "Where are these people coming from?"
Answer says, "They are unlikely to have come from anywhere."
Dangling footnotes, too.

Didn't vote myself, FWIW.